What is this pipe and how do i repair leaking
This is the bathroom sink. This pipe is leaking from somewhere around the area with the tan sealant. You can see it is kind of "jerry rigged" from the previous owners. Can i just reapply some "sealant" to reinforce the gaps.
I am not very experienced as you can see and just wondering if this is fixable with something basic. Also let me know what other info is needed. Maybe i need to know exactly where leak is coming from? Thanks


Yes, it is probably leaking from the overflow block.  Looks like it's sealed with plumbers putty.  You may be able to simply replace the putty and eliminate the leak, or you may need to resort to a silicone sealant.  No idea how the overflow is attached—can you get some better pics of that area?

If the the cover/box comes off, it will be nicer to clean off the old sealer.

If it’s leaking from the top, stop overflowing the sink. Job done.
